# How to use inputs in loops

Tags: python

I created a code that shows the digits in the Fibonacci sequence. I want a way to allow the user to enter the number of numbers shown. This is my code:

```
total = 1
total2 = 0
for i in range (*Number of numbers/2*):
    total = total + total2
    print (total)
    total2 = total + total2
    print (total2)
#Shows golden ratio
total3 = total2/total
print (total3)
```

Can someone help me? It would be great!

Comment: Gotta love good variable names

Comment: Gotta love convenient sarcasm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in Python 2.x of how to get an integer:

```
myNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
print(myNum + 1)
```

Edit: Untested Python 3 version:

```
myNum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(myNum + 1)
```

Comment: @astronautlevel I wonder how come `print (total3)` works in python 3.2.3

Comment: worked! thanks so much! Now is there a way to make it so that it DOESN'T have to print what myNum is? If there isn't that's fine!

Comment: never mind. Figured out how to implement a variable in a loop using this answer, and figured out how to not print. Thanks!

Comment: The second line was just an example to show that it is indeed an int. It can be omitted.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, parentheses around an expression don't change the expression.  `(3)` is the same as just `3`.  So, in Python 2.x, `print` is a statement that is followed by an expression, and it does no harm if the expression is in parentheses; while in Python 3.x, `print()` is a function and the parentheses are required to call the function.  At least on StackOverflow, I try to always write the parens after `print` because I try to write code that is good for both Python 2.x and Python 3.x where possible.

Comment: @steveha actually before the question's content was edited, the OP was using `print total3`  statement inside a python 3.2.3 program. I know the differences between python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary actually, my coding always said print(total3)

Answer (score 2):

**python 2.x:**

```
for i in xrange (int(raw_input())//2):    #use xrange() in python 2.x, 
                                          #it is similar to python 3.x's range()
```

**python 3.x:**

```
for i in range (int(input())//2):
```

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer - using python 3.2.3